# Discord bot can't kick user who blocked the bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

few days ago I wrote a little discord bot in python and it's running pretty good. But I just ran into a problem, it seems as the bot can't interact(give roles, kick, etc..) with users who blocked the bot.
Is there a way to fix that?

Functions like that don't work:

```
import random as r
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
server_name = client.get_guild(802985801100165200)
await member.send(f'Willkommen auf {server_name}!')
print(1)
rolle = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Member')
await member.add_roles(rolle)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx,member: discord.Member,*,reason=None):
await member.send(f'You were kicked from the Schnitzel Server {reason}')
await member.kick(reason=reason)
await ctx.send(f'Kicked {member} {reason}')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: We're gonna need a little more information. What have you written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bot can't send messages to someone who has blocked your bot. Trying to do so will raise a `discord.Forbidden 403 error`

You want to try and except for that scenario

original:

```py
await member.send(f'You were kicked from the Schnitzel Server {reason}')
await member.kick(reason=reason)
await ctx.send(f'Kicked {member} {reason}')
```

edited:

```py
try:
   await member.send(f'You were kicked from the Schnitzel Server {reason}')
except discord.Forbidden:
   await ctx.send("Failed to DM the user.") # will send if bot fails to DM the user
   # pass (if you don't want a failure indication and want to silently pass on error)
await member.kick(reason=reason) # this will function normally if bot fails to send message to user
await ctx.send(f'Kicked {member} {reason}')
```